# Clean SQL data by correcting rows that violate the functional dependency

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the functional dependency A->B and I need to clean the data by correcting rows that violate this FD. Currently the data is:

```
A        B
1        a
2        b
2        b
2        b
2        c
3        d
3        d
6        c
6        c
6        c
6        c
6        c
6        b
```

but I need it to be:

```
A        B
1        a
2        b
2        b
2        b
2        b
3        d
3        d
6        c
6        c
6        c
6        c
6        c
6        c
```

How can I do this within a query? I have an existing query that finds the correct value for B for each A value (for example, 1's correct value is a, 2's is b, 3's is d, 4's is c) but I'm not sure how to clean the data using a standard SELECT query.

Comment: You need to explain the logic here. So I guess you need the highest occurrence of `B` per `A`? What happens in the case of `(5;e),(5;f)`?

Comment: There's no `4` in the data, what do you mean by `4's is c`? Did you mean `6`?

Answer (score 0):

Craft an UPDATE or MERGE statement that only corrects those that you know are wrong to what you know is right.

Example update statement for MySql:

```
UPDATE yourtable t
JOIN
(
  SELECT 2 AS A, 'b' AS B 
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'd'
  UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'c'
) AS correction
 ON t.A = correction.A
  SET t.B = correction.B
WHERE t.B != correction.B
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=30b1b139ad706711f58edc3de4275dec)*